# How do I enable https for my site in Magento 1.9.3.7?

Tags: security, ssl, https, magento1.9.3

Where would I go in the Admin Panel of Magento 1.9.3.7 to change my site to be https and secure?

Thank you.

Comment: Have your site SSL installed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If SSL is configured on the server then you can easily enable HTTPS for your Magento website.

Steps are mentioned below:

- Login to admin panel and go to **System** > **Configuration** -> **General (Web)** section.
- Change the value of **Base URL** under **Unsecure** and **Secure** sub-sections from **`http`** to **`https`**.
- Change the value of **Use Secure URLs in Frontend** to **Yes**.
- **Optional:** Change the value of **Use Secure URLs in Admin** to **Yes**.
- Save config and remove Magento cache.